# Can I use jQuery to select a text node by its contents?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select an `<a href="...">foo</a>` DOM node, knowing `foo`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "foo";
}).doSomething();
```

There's also the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector if you don't need an exact match, like this:

```
$("a:contains('foo')").doSomething();
```

Instead of an exact match, this works if the text you're looking for is anywhere in the element.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to match exactly and do it often, create a selector for that, like this:

```
$.expr[":"].textEquals = function(obj, index, meta) { 
  return $(obj).text() === meta[3]; 
}
```

Then you could use it anytime after, like this:

```
$("a:textEquals('foo')").doSomething();
```